# Please tell me about the Manifest File in Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: json, google-app-engine, oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Act i'm developing the app in Google Apps Marketplace for a asp.net website. I'm stuck to selecting the manifest file i got both the options

A). the XML one
B). the JSON One

i'm confused which one is latest and which one is to use in app.
I'm using Oauth2 as the authenticating scenario. and using service account for further actions.

I'm waiting for the manifest file finalization which one is to use.

Please help me out guys.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the new format, should look something like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Welcome Aboard",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "a plain text description",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
    "16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
  },
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "428464274542"
}
```

You can find more info about listing a new app here: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing

Sadly there's no more info about manifest.json in there.